# How to get C-like performance when filling up a mutable buffer in GHC Haskell

Tags: haskell

I need to prefill up a mutable IOVector (with a given value).  The Haskell code I am using is

```
-- use Control.Monad, Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable, Data.Word, and run in IO monad
buff <- new buffsize::IO (IOVector Word8)
forM_ [0..buffsize-1] $ \p -> write buff p (100::Word8)
```

This runs 1-2 orders of magnitude slower than the comparable c code

```
char *buff = (char *) malloc(BUFFERSIZE);
char *maxbuff = buff + BUFFERSIZE;

for(char *p = buff; p < maxbuff; p++) *p = 0;
```

For instance, for buffsize=4000000000, it takes about 7 seconds in c, but about 3 minutes in Haskell.

(FYI, I am using Ubuntu running on an Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz, GHC version 7.8.4, but these specifics probably shouldn't matter)

Does anyone see any changes I could make to the Haskell code to get comparable speeds?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-O`? This runs in 3.8s for me.

Comment: Also, the idiomatic way to do this is using `replicate` from `Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable` which runs even faster.

Comment: @cchalmers That size overflows a 32-bit `Int`, so it's kind of misleading to compare a 32-bit system's results to a 64-bit system's results.

Comment: Please always give the GHC version when talking about performance!

Comment: @cchalmers- The problem with replicate is that in my real program, I am resizing using `grow`, and need to fill in the new memory afterwards.  I don't think replicate will help in that case.

Comment: @dfeuer- Sorry, I've added the version of GHC.

Comment: Thanks. You might be surprised by the performance effects of different GHC versions. There are sometimes dramatic changes (usually improvements).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three main things:

1. `write` is bounds-checked, while a direct pointer write in C isn't.  Change that to `unsafeWrite` if you want to keep C's lack of safety.
2. `forM_ [0..buffsize-1]` has overhead due to being optimized for generality. If you want to remove all the generality, like the C loop, write the loop as something directly recursive.
3. Use the llvm backend for code that needs to optimize tight loops.

I coded up a criterion benchmark to test a whole bunch of variants:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Vector.Unboxed.Mutable
import Data.Word

import Criterion.Main

buffsize :: Int
buffsize = 1000000

fillBuff1 :: IOVector Word8 -> IO ()
fillBuff1 buff = do
    forM_ [0..buffsize-1] $ \p -> write buff p 100

fillBuff2 :: IOVector Word8 -> IO ()
fillBuff2 buff = do
    forM_ [0..buffsize-1] $ \p -> unsafeWrite buff p 100

fillBuff3 :: IOVector Word8 -> IO ()
fillBuff3 buff = do
    let fill n | n < buffsize = unsafeWrite buff n 100 >> fill (n + 1)
               | otherwise    = return ()
    fill 0

fillBuff4 :: IOVector Word8 -> IO ()
fillBuff4 buff = do
    let fill n | n < buffsize = write buff n 100 >> fill (n + 1)
               | otherwise    = return ()
    fill 0

main = do
    buff <- new buffsize
    let b n f = bench n . whnfIO . f $ buff
    defaultMain [ b "original" fillBuff1
                , b "unsafeWrite" fillBuff2
                , b "unsafeWrite + recursive" fillBuff3
                , b "recursive" fillBuff4
                ]
```

Note that I'm only benchmarking filling, not allocation + filling.

Here's a typical session without llvm:

```
carl@debian:~/hask$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.8.4
carl@debian:~/hask$ ghc -O2 mutvectorwrite
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mutvectorwrite.hs, mutvectorwrite.o )
Linking mutvectorwrite ...
carl@debian:~/hask$ ./mutvectorwrite 
benchmarking original
time                 6.659 ms   (6.599 ms .. 6.728 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 6.638 ms   (6.599 ms .. 6.683 ms)
std dev              120.7 μs   (97.36 μs .. 165.9 μs)

benchmarking unsafeWrite
time                 5.413 ms   (5.319 ms .. 5.524 ms)
                     0.998 R²   (0.995 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 5.346 ms   (5.309 ms .. 5.394 ms)
std dev              127.4 μs   (85.00 μs .. 220.2 μs)

benchmarking unsafeWrite + recursive
time                 3.363 ms   (3.323 ms .. 3.409 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 3.371 ms   (3.343 ms .. 3.411 ms)
std dev              104.6 μs   (65.11 μs .. 187.1 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 16% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking recursive
time                 3.389 ms   (3.330 ms .. 3.438 ms)
                     0.998 R²   (0.996 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 3.435 ms   (3.424 ms .. 3.451 ms)
std dev              43.38 μs   (34.49 μs .. 67.38 μs)
```

And a typical session with llvm:

```
carl@debian:~/hask$ ghc -O2 -fllvm mutvectorwrite
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( mutvectorwrite.hs, mutvectorwrite.o )
Linking mutvectorwrite ...
carl@debian:~/hask$ ./mutvectorwrite 
benchmarking original
time                 5.302 ms   (5.251 ms .. 5.365 ms)
                     0.999 R²   (0.999 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 5.286 ms   (5.262 ms .. 5.322 ms)
std dev              87.47 μs   (63.29 μs .. 115.0 μs)

benchmarking unsafeWrite
time                 3.929 ms   (3.867 ms .. 4.001 ms)
                     0.998 R²   (0.996 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 4.039 ms   (3.994 ms .. 4.131 ms)
std dev              204.2 μs   (114.6 μs .. 378.5 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 30% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking unsafeWrite + recursive
time                 496.4 μs   (492.8 μs .. 500.8 μs)
                     0.999 R²   (0.998 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 496.6 μs   (492.8 μs .. 503.9 μs)
std dev              17.46 μs   (9.971 μs .. 31.42 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 27% (moderately inflated)

benchmarking recursive
time                 556.6 μs   (548.4 μs .. 563.8 μs)
                     0.998 R²   (0.996 R² .. 0.999 R²)
mean                 565.4 μs   (559.7 μs .. 574.3 μs)
std dev              23.95 μs   (16.41 μs .. 33.78 μs)
variance introduced by outliers: 35% (moderately inflated)
```

Performance gets down to pretty reasonable when you combine everything.

Comment: I'd be surprised if GHC doesn't monomorphise `forM_` as an optimisation.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if it does.  But I guess I might as well test!

Comment: OK, I did some benchmarking....  These suggestions don't help (sorry!).  In fact recursion slowed my down.  My original code: 3m55s....  My original code+unsafeWrite: 3m43....  Your code: 4m32s....  So, `unsafeWrite` helps, but only marginally.

Comment: @jamshidh That's not what my benchmarking is showing at all.  I'll include complete results.

Comment: @jamshidh I think my last test got reasonable results.

Comment: Please always give GHC versions with performance measurements.

Comment: @dfeuer I snuck it in there just now.

Comment: Yes!  It was the `-O` that did the trick (llvm didn't actually help me....  But no worries with the `-O`).  With `-O` it is actaully faster than C now.  Since your answer predated @cchalmers comment by a few mins, I am awarding the credit to this answer....

Comment: your "do" notations in the fillBuff functions are useless here.

Comment: @qleguennec Eh. They're the result of aggressive refactoring. Lots of people prefer to keep them around just to make further refactoring easier. I don't care much, but the fact that I left them around without thinking sort of proves their point.

Answer (score 2):

The most correct way to do this is to use `set`. Specifically, use `slice` to select the portion of the vector you wish to fill, then use `set` to fill it. If any other approach benchmarks faster (fairly unlikely), you should file a bug report.

#### Edit

See the top of [No_signal's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29157334/1477667) for an implementation of this idea.

Answer (score 1):

edit : i will just put this here

```
growAndFill :: (Unbox a) => Int -> a -> IOVector a -> IO (IOVector a)
growAndFill i x v = do
                newV <- V.grow v i
                V.set (V.unsafeSlice (V.length v) i newV) x
                return newV
```

edit : go with slice then set over this (look at code above)

This should work and it is very fast.

The code is based on the set function

```
unsafeFill :: (Unbox a) => IOVector a -> Int -> Int -> a -> IO ()
unsafeFill !v lo hi x
    | hi < lo    = return ()
    | otherwise = do
                unsafeWrite v lo x
                do_set 1
    where
      hi' = hi - lo + 1
      do_set i | 2*i < hi' = do unsafeCopy (unsafeSlice (lo+i) i v)
                                              (unsafeSlice lo i v)
                                do_set (2*i)
               | otherwise = unsafeCopy (unsafeSlice (lo+i) (hi'-i) v)
                                             (unsafeSlice lo (hi'-i) v)

fillBuff5 :: IOVector Word8 -> IO ()
fillBuff5 buff = unsafeFillSlice buff 0 (buffsize-1) 100
```

results compiled with -O2

```
benchmarking original
time                 691.7 μs   (689.6 μs .. 694.6 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 691.2 μs   (690.2 μs .. 692.6 μs)
std dev              3.848 μs   (3.054 μs .. 5.367 μs)

benchmarking unsafeWrite
time                 552.9 μs   (551.7 μs .. 554.2 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 552.9 μs   (551.9 μs .. 554.1 μs)
std dev              3.485 μs   (2.617 μs .. 5.655 μs)

benchmarking unsafeWrite + recursive
time                 549.8 μs   (546.1 μs .. 553.7 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 554.4 μs   (552.7 μs .. 556.3 μs)
std dev              6.096 μs   (4.802 μs .. 7.698 μs)

benchmarking recursive
time                 827.9 μs   (823.9 μs .. 831.0 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (1.000 R² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 817.9 μs   (815.3 μs .. 821.5 μs)
std dev              10.43 μs   (9.140 μs .. 12.49 μs)

benchmarking unsafeFill
time                 65.13 μs   (64.74 μs .. 65.57 μs)
                     1.000 R²   (0.999 RÂ² .. 1.000 R²)
mean                 65.20 μs   (64.88 μs .. 66.17 μs)
std dev              1.839 μs   (731.5 ns .. 3.667 μs)
```

Comment: That code is kind of hilarious. I seem to remember a relatively recent discussion about offering this sort of fill feature in `Data.Vector`. I wonder if it's in the GitHub master. Er... actually, maybe that was something else, and this is already available? Can't remember.

Comment: Oh, I see. You copied the default `basicSet` implementation. Why do that instead of just using `set` on a slice, which should be faster?

Comment: I did not think of it.